# What does it mean when there are two versions of the same gem listed in parentheses in a gem list?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

When I execute `gem list`, I see that there are some gems that have two (or even three) versions listed. For example:

```
faraday (0.15.2, 0.11.0)
```

From what I've read, one cannot use two versions of the same gem. If that's the case, what does this mean? How can I tell which version is actually being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shows all the versions that are installed locally. By default the newest one will be used unless bundler (via `Gemfile`) is configured to use another one.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to remove the old unused versions of the gem:

```
gem cleanup faraday
```

Leave out the `faraday` if you'd like to clean up all old versions of all gems, and add `--dryrun` if you'd like to see which versions are to be deleted, without deleting them.